# autoconf without install files

Tags: configure, autoconf, automake

I have started recently to work with automake and autoconf and I am a little confused about how to distribute the code.

Usually when I get a code that works with a configure file, the only thing that I get is a confiure file and the code itself with the Makefile.am and so on. Usually I do

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and thats all but when I generate my configure from a configure.ac file it toss out lots of files that I thought where just temporary but if I give the code to a partner and he makes configure, it doesn't work, it needs either remake the autoreconf or have all this files (namely instal.sh,config.sub...).

Is there something that I am missing? How can I distribute the code easily and clean? 
I have searched a lot but I think I am searching for the right thing because I cannot find anything useful.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automake provides a `make dist` target.  This automatically creates a `.tar.gz` from your project.  This archive is set up in such a way that the recipient can simply extract it and run the usual `./configure && make && make install` invocation.

It is generally **not recommended** to check the files generated by Autotools into your repository.  This is because they are derived objects.  You wouldn't check in your `.o` files!

Usually, it is a good idea to provide a `autogen.sh` script that carries out any actions required to re-create the Autotools build infrastructure in a new version control system checkout.  Often, it can be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/sh
autoreconf -i
```

Then set it `chmod +x`, and the instructions for compiling from a clean checkout can be `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have my project in a git repository and I would like to have what is needed to run the usual commands. Is it possible to create what is needed and add just that to the repository instead of a tar.gz?

Comment: It's **possible**, but it's generally a **bad idea**.  Please see updated answer.

Comment: ok, I will do that then. I have seen several packages with a single configure file that works but maybe it has been generated in a different way. I will add the autogen script then. Thanks!

Comment: `autogen.sh` has been deprecated, use the `bootstrap` name instead. Also, it's a good idea to do a `make distcheck`, that will not only package the source code for distribution, it will also extract it in another directory, build it from there, and run tests (if there are any), and ONLY THEN, will print that the .tar.gz is ready for distribution.

Comment: Interesting — where can I find out more about the deprecation of `autogen.sh`? And yes, `make distcheck` is incredibly useful!

Comment: @PeterT.B.Brett The [Autotools FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/faq/autotools-faq.html#What-does-_002e_002fbootstrap-or-_002e_002fautogen_002esh-do_003f) says "The name bootstrap is preferred over ‘autogen.sh’ as there also exists an independent software package named AutoGen.".